# I want to remove credit card information from Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, privacy

Please let me know how can I change my credit card information that I entered when I set up the Play Store.

Answer (score 8):

Go to [payments.google.com](https://payments.google.com/manage/w/0/#paymentMethods:), sign in with the same account you used to set up the Play Store, select **Payment Methods**, click the **Edit** or **Remove** link next to the card you want to edit/delete

For more info, refer to the [Google Payments Help Center](https://support.google.com/payments/?hl=en)